# MVC Control for pdf viewer not consistent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<object id='pdfbox' style="width:900px; height:800px;" type="application/pdf" 
    data="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { sID = this.Model.sID })">
</object>
```

This control is used to show the pdf files in the view .

This control works fine in some systems but in build and some other machines ,it is not working .Is something needs to be installed?

Comment: Do the machines have PDF viewer installed?

Comment: Yes Adobe Reader X1 is installed

Answer (score 0):

With a little search I found this:

You can embed the PDF in a partial view then update the partial view via ajax with the PDF on the form submit button.

```
@model Test.Models.ViewModel

<style type="text/css">

#pdfbox
{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
}

</style>

<object id='pdfbox' type="application/pdf" data="@Url.Action("GeneratePDF", "Home", Model)">
    Click @Html.ActionLink("here", "GeneratePDF", "Home") to view the file.
</object>
```

//Controller

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(ViewModel model)
    {

        byte[] bytes = OpenPDFAndGetBytes("Thepdfname");
        return File(bytes, "application/pdf");
    }

    public ActionResult RenderPDF(LabelViewModel model)
    {
        return PartialView(model);
    }

//main view


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RenderPDF", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "pdf" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Fill the form:</legend>
                        Some form junk can go here
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Display PDF" />
                </fieldset>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id='pdf'>
                    @{
                        Html.RenderPartial("RenderPDF", Model);
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

[Sourcer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721529/pdf-viewer-in-mvc-to-show-the-pdf-contents-in-view)