# Reading a PDF document as part of the while specifying which PDF to render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

[Expanding on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439634/view-pdf-as-part-of-the-page), I'm struggling to work out how I can specify which PDF I'm reading.

I'm creating my PDF with `WkHtmlToPdf` which generates the PDF file. I'm then saving the PDF bytes to my database and I want to read it out again to display it on the View:

```
public void GetPDF(int id)
{
    // get the byte array for the PDF out of the database
    var Pdf = db.Invoices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Document;

    //FileStream Stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    //return File(Stream, "application/pdf");

    // this code reads from a file but I need to read the byte array
    // back out so that it displays as a PDF
}
```

On my View, I'm doing this as per the answer in the linked question:

```html
<object data='@Url.Action("GetPDF")'></object>
```

How do I pass in the Invoice ID parameter into the `GetPDF` method?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Has this question been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Url.Action("GetPDF", new { id = 1 })
```

Comment: I really should have thought about that but I guess I was overcomplicating as usual ^^

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to read the byte array back out so that it displays as a PDF

```
public ActionResult GetPDF(int id) {
    // get the byte array for the PDF out of the database
    var Pdf = db.Invoices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Document;
    // return Pdf content
    return File(Pdf, "application/pdf");    
}
```

**[Controller.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx)** has an overloaded method that takes a `byte[]` of the file content to be returned. So return the result of passing the byte array to that method.

And @RosdiKasim already showed you how to call the action with the id from the view

```
@Url.Action("GetPDF", new { id = 1 })
```