# C# MVC display pdf in a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I currently have a partial view with the following line to return a pdf file:

```
<embed src="@Url.Action( "GenerateBill", "Bill" )" width="100%" height="600" />
```

However, instead of retrieve the pdf this way, I want to save the pdf into a view model and return it. so the code can be like this:

```
<embed src="@Model.CurrentBillData" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600" />
```

But I am getting a blank page back. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Any help found here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439634/view-pdf-as-part-of-the-page

Comment: Put an iframe in a partial view and bind it to the pdf document. Then use the partial view in your other views

Comment: Return it as stream, then the browser should take care of the rest as long as you state the type.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath, no luck. tried to return as FileStreamResult with memoryStream, and "application/pdf", I got a blank pdf file.

Comment: nevermind. I forgot to set the position of the stream to 0.