# Return Success/Error message with pdf file using actionresult or fileresult from controller in Asp.Net Core Web Api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to return pdf file as response with 'success or 'error' message but as of now getting pdf file and its downloading by using this code 'return File(bytes, "application/pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".pdf");' now i want to return pdf file with success or error message. How to achieve this can anyone help me out of this

Comment: I recommend to return view model that contains file content as byte[] and message (success or false) and pass this model to view and render pdf as part of page reference to this article  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439634/view-pdf-as-part-of-the-page   with showing message on the page or on alert

Comment: @MohamedAdel used view model but getting file response in json format with file and content details.not downloading file and this is a web api and want to download file and need to display message

Comment: Please add your method with view model to question

Comment: return new Response { Data = new DocVm() { Documents = File(bytes, "application/pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".pdf"), message = "Ok" } }; and the model is  public class DocVm     {   public FileResult Documents { get; set;             public string message{ get; set; }


        }

Comment: Just send file content as (byte[]) and handle view or download on frontend layer

Comment: byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(responseobj.Data.ToString());
                        if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0)
                        {

                            return new Response { Data = new DocVm() { Documents = File(bytes, "application/pdf", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".pdf"), message = "Ok" } };
please have a look into this im returning like this

Comment: Don't return file just return bytes directly and manage it at frontend layer.    return new Response { Data = new DocVm() { Documents = bytes, message = "Ok" } };